# combine two functions in Excel

Tags: excel, function

I would like to combine two functions (excel 2013).

I have this function:
`=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(H3:H1002="";IF(C3:C1002="PRODUCT";MATCH(B3:B1002;B3:B1002;0)));ROW(B3:B1002)-ROW(B3)+1);1))`

..and want to combine with this function: 
`=SUMIF(C:C;"OTHER PRODUCT";B:B)`

ONLY IF the value in row B3:B1002 is between 1-500 (numerical), otherwise count rows separately and use the first function on top above.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given comments below I have completely revised my answer. Try this formula

`=SUMIFS(B3:B1000;C3:C1000;"OTHER";B3:B1000;"<=500";H3:H1000;"")+SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(H3:H1000="";IF(C3:C1000="OTHER";IF(B3:B1000>500;MATCH(B3:B1000;B3:B1000;0))));ROW(B3:B1000)-ROW(B3)+1);1))`

confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

That will sum any numbers <= 500 in column B, for the specified product and where column H is blank, but also add 1 for every distinct text value or number above 500

Comment: It's almost what i wanted but theres a catch.

the rows in B i will give a value 1-500 only if theres huge quantities of mass products at once, otherwise i will give it its own ID, in form of: 15-23960966 - then it should distinguish and count the uniqe products with its ID's separately.

E.g.

Comment: but if there was another 30 or ABCAC in there the result would still be 44 because you don't include duplicates? If the other products always have non-numeric id's then I think you can effectively add the two formulas, my version added to your original, although you need another clause in the original to exclude numbers, I'll edit my answer to that effect.....

Comment: excel says that there is a error in the function (too few arguments)

Comment: Yes, those would be unique ID's, if there is duplicate then i don't need to count that. The products which are in large quantities dont need ID's (they are count together with no ID)

Comment: But, how can i combine the formulas you gave to count as one after 500?

Comment: There was a typo in the second formula (too many parentheses) _ I have corrected that and added a version which does everything - but I recommend, initially at least, that you keep two separate formulas - if there are any discrepancies you can at least know which formula is not giving the result you expect

Comment: If i add a alphabet then it counts as 1, counting distinct values works as well.
If i add 15-3325235 then it counts as 1, counting distinct values works as well.
if i add any number up to 500 then it counts as that same number but i dont need district there.
Lets say if i have 2 x 30 amounts of products, then it counts as 30 still.
Another thing is that when i type number over 500 then it needs to be like 1 product, currently It outputs nothing 0.

Comment: OK - that would have been a better explanation to put in your question - tells me almost everything I need to know - this is all for a specific text value in column B? I'll post a revised formula....

Comment: Yes, this is all working now as i wanted, perfecto!
Thank You very much. I would like those knowledge that you got.